# Convert exe file to IL (Intermediate Language)

Tags: il

Is there any Command-Line or programmatically way to convert any type of exe file to IL?!

I know it is possible cuz I saw several programs that show me IL codes.

Note : I do this for .Net Framework via ILDASM.EXE (A tool of visual studio) but I'm not able to do the same work for the exe files which don't have CLR header (similarly it is only a way for convert .Net assemblies!).

Comment: You can't convert an arbitrary executable into CIL if it wasn't compiled into CIL in the first place, so no, I don't believe such a tool exists.

Comment: @vcsjones ... I mean Hex Rays IDA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know it is possible cuz I saw several programs that show me IL codes.
>   I mean Hex Rays IDA

From the [Hex Rays IDA site](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/):

> IDA is a Windows, Linux or Mac OS X hosted multi-processor disassembler and debugger that offers so many features it is hard to describe them all.

And when you look at the screenshots, you will notice the code there is not IL, it's x86 assembly.

If assembly is what you want, then getting that is mostly trivial and there are [many programs](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Disassemblers_and_Decompilers#x86_Disassemblers) that can do that.

If you really want IL, then getting that doesn't make much sense and I'm not aware of anything that would do that.